# how to make a picturebox.enter event

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to make a game . i am using pictureboxes . 
the concept is that when the pcbox hit the other one it adds points . 
so i wanted an event like mouse enter for the pictureboxes
( when a picture box enters the other one ) .
i tried this code but it isn't so efficient

```
 If pc1.left = pc2.left - 120 Then 
 Call MsgBox("whatever") 
 ElseIf pc1.left = pc2.left + 120 Then 
 call msgbox("hit")
 EndIf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid pictureboxes flying around, but here is my answer nonetheless:

```
 Dim rectangle1 as Rectangle = pc1.Bounds 
 Dim rectangle2 as Rectangle = pc2.Bounds

 If (rectangle1.IntersectsWith(rectangle2)) Then
    //whatever
 Else
    //hit
 EndIf
```

or even

```
 If (pc1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pc2.Bounds)) Then
    //whatever
 Else
    //hit
 EndIf
```

This detects any intersection of the pictureboxes, but as I mentioned, this is no appropiate way of programming games in vb.net.

Maybe you should consider reading [this guide](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/39686-creating-a-fully-functional-pong-game/) about programming a simple ping-pong game (without controls as actors).

Comment: No probs ;) If you want to program "something big" you shouldn't use pictureboxes and so on, but for a little bit of playing around with vb.net it's okay of course...